# Arralist remove duplicate name and modify another arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arraylist with the name of who pay something, and another arraylist with the cost of each payment.
For example:

- nameArray = Nicola, Raul, Lorenzo, Raul, Raul, Lorenzo, Nicola
- priceArray = 24, 12, 22, 18, 5, 8, 1

I need to sum the cost of each person. So the array must become:

- nameArray = Nicola, Raul, Lorenzo
- price Array = 25, 35, 30
  And then, ordering the array by price, so:
- nameArray = Raul, Lorenzo, Nicola
- priceArray = 35, 30, 25

I already done the ordering part, but I don't know how to sum each cost per person and then remove the duplicate string/cost value.
This is my code:

```
 public void bubble_sort(ArrayList<String> nameArray, ArrayList<BigDecimal> priceArray) {
    Map<String, BigDecimal> totals = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.size(); ++i) {
        String name = nameArray.get(i);
        BigDecimal price = priceArray.get(i);

        BigDecimal total = totals.get(name);

        if (total != null) {
            totals.put(name, total + price);
        } else {
            totals.put(name, price);
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry : totals.entrySet()) {
        nameArray.add(entry.getKey());
        priceArray.add(entry.getValue());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < priceArray.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < priceArray.size() - 1; j++) {
            if (priceArray.get(j).compareTo(priceArray.get(j + 1)) < 0) {
                BigDecimal tempPrice = priceArray.get(j);
                String tempName = nameArray.get(j);
                priceArray.set(j, priceArray.get(j + 1));
                nameArray.set(j, nameArray.get(j + 1));
                priceArray.set(j + 1, tempPrice);
                nameArray.set(j + 1, tempName);
            }

        }

    }
```

I cannot sum bigdecimal on line totals.put(name, total + price);
How should I correct the code?

Comment: You have to make sure to use new `List` objects in the second `for` loop (or else you'll take e.g. `[A,B,C,B]` and turn it into `[A,B,C,B,A,B,C]`. If you really want to use the same ones, you can call `clear()` on them before doing the second loop

Comment: @BenP. thank you, I did it this way and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using a `Map` to store each person's name and a running total of their purchases.

```
Map<String, Integer> totals = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.size(); ++i) {
    String name = nameArray.get(i);
    int price = priceArray.get(i);

    Integer total = totals.get(name);

    if (total != null) {
        totals.put(name, total + price);
    } else {
        totals.put(name, price);
    }
}
```

At this point, you have a `Map` containing an entry for each person and the total amount they've spent. You can create new `List`s for each `Map.Entry` and then use your existing sorting code.

```
List<String> uniqueNames = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> uniquePrices = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : totals.entrySet()) {
    uniqueNames.add(entry.getKey());
    uniquePrices.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

Of course, you could sort the lists as you build them from the `entrySet()`, but what you have now ought to work as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer..there are still some problems...I change all the "integer" type to BigDecimal, because the array of price is BigDecimal type. But at line totals.put(name, total + price); it says "operator + cannot be applied to java.lang.bigdecimal". How can I solve this? Check out my question again, I've update the code

Comment: Use the `add()` method, like `totals.put(name, total.add(price))`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the HashMap combined with List to store all values:
Example:

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> listNamesPrices = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> nicolaPrices= new ArrayList<>();
nicolaPrices.add(24);
nicolaPrices.add(1);
listNamesPrices.put("Nicola", nicolaPrices);
int sum=0;
for (int i : prices){
    sum += i;
}
// sum will be 25 (24 + 1) at end, after that You can make another HashMap of <String, int>
// and store <"name",sum> in it, e.g. Nicola,25
HashMap<String, Integer> listNameSum = new HashMap<>();
listNameSum.put("Nicola",sum);
```